# Way to make backspace delete whole words at a time

Tags: javascript, angularjs-directive, angular

I have a text area:

```
<textarea type="input"  id="txtText">Hello+world-how*are+you</textarea>
```

I want a way for backspace to delete a whole word every time it is clicked using Javascript or Angular js.
When I press backspace I want it to split by operators and delete from the end. The first backspaces in the above example would delete 'you' then 'are' then 'how' and so on.
But if the mouse is on 'world' then it deletes 'world' first, then 'Hello'.

Comment: Why `+` as seperator? And you shouldn't need `contenteditable` on at `textarea`

Comment: Something to start : http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/63jY6/

Comment: Or you can use CTRL+Backspace and it does what you want

Comment: @Weedoze: In my application I want to delete by word. And I took reference on above link. But it split by one character. But I want to split by multiple character. And also controlled by mouse click position.

Comment: You should try something first and seek help if you can't figure out how you can meet your target through that path.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution than uses the `data` attribute to match for changes: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/63jY6/69/)

```js
jQuery('#EditableDiv').keyup(function(e) {
  if (jQuery(e.target).text().length < jQuery(e.target).attr("data-value").length) {
    var data = jQuery(e.target).attr("data-value").split(" ");
    var text = jQuery(e.target).text().split(" ");
    for (var a = 0; a < data.length; a++) {
      if (text[a] != data[a]) {
        text.splice(a, 1);
        break;
      }
    }
    jQuery(e.target).text(text.join(" "));
  }
  jQuery(e.target).attr("data-value", jQuery(e.target).text());

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="EditableDiv" contenteditable="true" data-value="Hello, how are you" class="size">Hello, how are you</div>
```