# HTML ContentEditable madness in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, cross-browser, contenteditable

I have this simple code:

```html
<div contenteditable="true" style="border: 1px solid black;"><input type="button" value="This is a button" /></div>
```

When I load this html in Chrome/Safari the cursor works as it should the enitre button is treated as a simple character and I can move right and left and a single delete or back space deletes the button.

But in FF latest and greatest build the cursor movement doesn't happen at all! It's driving me nuts.

But when I changed to this code:

```html
<div contenteditable="true" style="border: 1px solid black;"><img src="image url" /></div>
```

the image is treated well with cursor, i.e. when I press left and right keys I can see the cursor moving as it should, but this doesn't happen when I use input type=button, although that works very well in Chrome and Safari.

I need to treat group of characters as a single element that is not editable, that was the need for using group of characters in a button.

Comment: Can you be a little more clear about what you mean by "treating a group of characters as a single element that is not editable"?

Comment: You're probably going to need to make the alphabet, symbols and numbers as div elements with graphical representation and some attribute defining its value, and plenty of JS

Comment: @DerekBrown What I mean by "Group of characters as a word is ": say I have typed "sunny day today", i would like to treat day as a single character in content editable div, that means when I have my cursor near day, i.e. "sunny day| today" | = cursor, now when I hit back space i want day to be deleted instead of just y, so the output should be "sunny today"

Comment: @user2067797 would something like this be applicable? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38261431/way-to-make-backspace-delete-whole-words-at-a-time

Comment: @DerekBrown that would be an overkill, ideal way is if I am missing som CSS setting in Firefox so that I can get the same behaviour as chrome or safari